magento 2.4.7 display price of out of stock configurable products
I tried this link : Magento2: show price for out of stock configurable products
and this link also : enter link description here
but does not work for me !!
my configurable product always return 0 price
please help me with this !!!


Create a di.xml file under the etc folder of your custom module and add the following code:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="Vendor\Module\CustomerData\DefaultItem"/>
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>


Create the FinalPriceBox.php file under the Pricing/Render folder under your custom module like "Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render" and add the following code:

<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $result = BasePriceBox::_toHtml();
        if ($this->isMsrpPriceApplicable()) {
            /** @var BasePriceBox $msrpBlock */
            $msrpBlock = $this->rendererPool->createPriceRender(
                MsrpPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                $this->getSaleableItem(),
                [
                    'real_price_html' => $result,
                    'zone' => $this->getZone(),
                ]
            );
            $result = $msrpBlock->toHtml();
        }

        return $this->wrapResult($result);
    }
}

After implementing the above steps, the final price will be displayed for configurable products that are out of stock.
Screenshot for reference : https://prnt.sc/JUgRrbVDaCEl

I already mentioned that this solution does not work !!
